# passive (non-intrusive) progress bar notification

Tags: notification-area, notify-osd

How can I get passive (non-intrusive) progress bar?

A combination of kdialog --passivepopup and kdialog --progressbar. For example, when copying files with dolphin such a progress bar will be used. I want the same for my own scripts.

It's one KDE, but I would also install any other notification system.

Comment: Possibly more suitable for stackoverflow. Which language are you using?

Comment: Feel free to move. I am using Bash.